# How is it possible that 127==127 while 128!=128?

Tags: java

```
Integer v1_1 = 127;
Integer v1_2 = 127;

Integer v2_1 = 128;
Integer v2_2 = 128;

System.out.println(v1_1 == v1_2);//true
System.out.println(v2_1 == v2_2);//false
```

Why second expression is **false**?

I couldn't figure it out how the value affect the comparison result.

Comment: Never use `==` to compare objects.  (The way Java does "boxing" is very confusing to the novice -- worse than not having it at all, IMO.)

Comment: I know i never use it that way but i just wonder how could it be, now i understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `Integer` type **interns** the values (by the static class [`IntegerCache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache)) from -128 to 127.

Answer (score 3):

Because Integer class uses `IntegerCache` internally which caches object from `-128` to `127`. For e.g. When you call `valueOf` , the Integer class checks whether value is in the cache or not like this

```
   public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
        if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
            return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
        return new Integer(i);
    }
```

If the value exists in cache then you get the same object. Thats why

```
System.out.println(v1_1 == v1_2);//returns true
```