# why is (Integer) 1 == (Integer) 1 returns true, but (Integer) 200 == (Integer) 200 returns false?

Tags: java

I tried to print the results, but unable to get the reason behind this.Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language? How do you "print" it? Show us some code.

Comment: Uh what language is this?

Comment: I tried printing in java:

Comment: System.out.println( (Integer)1 == (Integer) 1);
  System.out.println( (Integer)200 ==  (Integer)200);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess we're talking about [java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn8c1.png)? (:

Java has a very weird way of storing integers. I can give you the long answer, [but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127) it [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code) be [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223555/java-comparison-not-working-when-integer-larger-than-128) found [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024933/why-equal-operator-works-for-integer-value-until-128-number) the [forums.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922211/how-is-it-possible-that-127-127-while-128-128)

Long story short, when integers pass 127, their length becomes too long to store normally, and thus the default comparing operator between them does not work properly. If you need to make this comparison, I'd advise using some other numeric type, but usually just storing them and using the `.equals()` function would do - It compares objects by value. Example:

```
//in some package , inside some function
// if((Integer)128==(Integer)128) 
// {
//    // this will never happen
// }
// if((Integer)128).equals((Integer)128))
   {
      // this will happen.
   }
```

Comment: I tried in java language. So, what exactly happens when it crosses 127 limit.

Comment: @gautamtyagi The links describe this pretty well. :)

Comment: "*when integers pass 127, their length becomes too long to store normally, and thus the default comparing operator between them does not work properly*" - This is not a good/correct explanation of what's going on.